# Products not showing on webpage depending on browser/operating system?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the products off this page: https://www.houseofmalt.co.uk/shop/?orderby=date

However some of the newest products (currently GlenAllachie 18 and GlenAllachie 30) are not showing depending on web browser and/or operating system. I've asked multiple people and some can or cannot see these new products. Whether these new products display or not does not seem to be definitive depending on browser or OS but that's my best guess so far.

The only thing I can see is under XHR, TrustBoxImpression contains the information of the missing product(s) so this could potentially be blocking it somehow?

I've tried changing my User Agent to Windows/OSX/Chrome/Safari but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: So, what's seems to be the problem here?

Comment: @baduker I'm trying to scrape the page including the newest products, however they are not appearing. I am unsure why. Changing my user agent to different browsers/OS does not help

Comment: Use a network sniffer to compare the requests. If the same request returns different responses on different machines it could be a IP/geo location filter. Then you could use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some proxy services like [Bright Proxy](https://brightdata.grsm.io/create)
Might be some antibot ip blacklisting